# Rename all files in a folder with sequencenumber if file exists Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, sequence, rename

I have this script:

```
#Variables
$src = "C:\Temp\test_script"
$dest = "C:\Temp\test_script"
$num= 1

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    # Trim filename without sequencenumbers
    $TrimmedName= $_.name.substring(0,16) 
    # Get extension of filename
    $ext= $_.Extension 
    # Get filename without sequencenumber but with extension  
    $FullName= $TrimmedName + $ext 
    # Get the path to be used
    $newpath = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $FullName

    # If path exists loop untill there is a free sequence number 
    if (Test-Path -Path $newpath) {

    while ((Test-Path -Path $newpath) -eq $true)
    {
       $newpath = Join-Path $dest ($TrimmedName + "_$num" + $_.Extension)    
       $num+=1 
    }
    Rename-Item $_.pspath -NewName $newpath
    }
    # If path does not exist rename file without a sequence number
    else { Rename-Item $_.pspath -NewName $newpath } 
}
```

What I want to do is rename files in a folder to this type: PHOTO_LR_1000001.jpg 
In this folder there are also files like this: 
PHOTO_LR_1000001_2.jpg or PHOTO_LR_1000001 2.jpg or PHOTO_LR_1000001_V2.jpg or PHOTO_LR_1000001 V2.jpg

When a filename already exists it must be given a sequence number like  
PHOTO_LR_1000001_1.jpg, PHOTO_LR_1000001_2.jpg, ...

But when the file does not already exists it must not add a sequence number.

I want to have this structure:
PHOTO_LR_1000001.jpg 
PHOTO_LR_1000001_1.jpg 
PHOTO_LR_1000001_2.jpg 
PHOTO_LR_1000001_3.jpg 
...

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few changes here...

$TrimmedName= $_.name.substring(0,16) <-- needs to be (0,15) since we start at 0, not 1.

I changed your Rename-Item to use the built in $_.MoveTo() method. It seemed simpler for your purposes.

Also, I did a single call for it at the end of the ForEach loop, since you were basically telling it If(try $newname) Then (update $newname until unique; use $newname) else (use $newname) so I just removed the redundancy due to you renaming the file one way or the other.

Added check to make sure your Test-Path isn't failing because it finds itself.

Moved $num=1 to within the ForEach loop so that it resets itself with each file.

```
#Variables
$src = "C:\Temp\test_script"
$dest = "C:\Temp\test_script"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    # Trim filename without sequencenumbers
    $TrimmedName= $_.name.substring(0,15) 
    # Get extension of filename
    $ext= $_.Extension 
    # Get filename without sequencenumber but with extension  
    $FullName= $TrimmedName + $ext 
    # Get the path to be used
    $newpath = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $FullName
    # Reset numerator in case trimmed file name is in use
    $num= 1

    # Make sure we don't fail the Test-Path because it finds and conflicts with itself
    if(!($NewPath -eq $_.FullName)){

    # If path exists loop untill there is a free sequence number 
    if (Test-Path $newpath) {
    while ((Test-Path $newpath))
    {
       $newpath = Join-Path $dest ($TrimmedName + "_$num" + $ext)    
       if(!($NewPath -eq $_.FullName)){
           $num+=1
       }
       else{break}
    }
    }
    # If path does not exist rename file without a sequence number
    $_.MoveTo($newpath)
}}
```

Leave a comment if you have any questions or issues, but it worked fine for my test.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply! I added an answer because it was too long to add it as a comment.

Comment: I have updated the script with a check within the While loop to break out if the updated path is also the current fullname (i.e. `if C:\Temp\Test_Script\PHOTO_LR_100005_1.jpg = C:\Temp\Test_Script\PHOTO_LR_100005_1.jpg then break loop`)

Answer (score 0):

If I run the script the first time everything works fine.
    Directory: C:\Temp\test_script

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        14/07/2011     21:36      46039 PHOTO_LR_1000001.jpg
-a---        13/07/2011      2:29      41502 PHOTO_LR_1000002.jpg
-a---         4/03/2009     20:33       7569 PHOTO_LR_1000003.jpg
-a---         8/03/2009      2:33      14523 PHOTO_LR_1000004.jpg
-a---         7/03/2009      4:33       6754 PHOTO_LR_1000005.jpg
-a---         6/03/2009      1:33       6536 PHOTO_LR_1000005_1.jpg
-a---         7/03/2009     20:33      11990 PHOTO_LR_1000006.jpg
-a---         8/03/2009      8:33       6939 PHOTO_LR_1000007.jpg
-a---         6/03/2009     15:33       7656 PHOTO_LR_1000007_1.jpg

But if I run it the second time, it doesn't work anymore.
Directory: C:\Temp\test_script

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        14/07/2011     21:36      46039 PHOTO_LR_1000001.jpg
-a---        13/07/2011      2:29      41502 PHOTO_LR_1000002.jpg
-a---         4/03/2009     20:33       7569 PHOTO_LR_1000003.jpg
-a---         8/03/2009      2:33      14523 PHOTO_LR_1000004.jpg
-a---         7/03/2009      4:33       6754 PHOTO_LR_1000005.jpg
-a---         6/03/2009      1:33       6536 PHOTO_LR_1000005_2.jpg
-a---         7/03/2009     20:33      11990 PHOTO_LR_1000006.jpg
-a---         8/03/2009      8:33       6939 PHOTO_LR_1000007.jpg
-a---         6/03/2009     15:33       7656 PHOTO_LR_1000007_2.jpg

As you can see, 
instead of keeping the PHOTO_LR_1000007_1.jpg it renames it to PHOTO_LR_1000007_2.jpg.

The script has to run several times a week so the renaming of an already renamed file is a problem.